# How to reduce Autoscaling Stabilization period to 2 min

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to reduce Autoscaling Stabilization period to 2 min.  i guess it is 10 minutes by default. But i want to reduce the Scale down time to few mins than longer. I searched around on net to discover the possibilities to check on this but cant find

how to configure to reduce  the scale down stabilization period

Answer (score 1):

You may change the initialization period to your desired parameter. Here are the steps:

1. Go to Instance groups under the Compute Engine section.
2. Click the name of the desired managed instance group then click edit.
3. Under Autoscaling, click Configure Autoscaling.
4. Look for "Initialization period" then set your required time for cooldown then click Save.

For more information you may visit this link.[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler#cool_down_period